# Memory allocation on the stack

Tags: assembly, memory, stack-variables

Here is a sample function reverse engineered from an easy program:

```
main            proc near
var_70          = dword ptr -70h
var_6C          = dword ptr -6Ch
var_68          = dword ptr -68h
i_2             = dword ptr -54h
i               = dword ptr -4
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub     esp, 70h
mov     [esp+70h+i], 0
jmp     short loc_804840A
￼￼￼loc_80483F7:
mov     eax, [esp+70h+i]
mov     edx, [esp+70h+i]
add     edx, edx
mov     [esp+eax*4+70h+i_2], edx
add     [esp+70h+i], 1
loc_804840A:
cmp     [esp+70h+i], 13h
jle     short loc_80483F7
mov     [esp+70h+i], 0
jmp     short loc_8048441
loc_804841B:
mov    eax, [esp+70h+i]
mov    edx, [esp+eax*4+70h+i_2]
mov    eax, offset aADD ; "a[%d]=%d\n"
mov    [esp+70h+var_68], edx
mov    edx, [esp+70h+i]
mov    [esp+70h+var_6C], edx
mov    [esp+70h+var_70], eax
call   _printf
add    [esp+70h+i], 1
loc_8048441:
cmp    [esp+70h+i], 13h
jle     short loc_804841B
mov    eax, 0
leave 
retn
main   endp

C code

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[20];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        a[i]=i*2;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        printf ("a[%d]=%d\n", i, a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why is memory not allocated consecutively and why are some parts of the memory in between `esp + 70h -54h` and `esp + 70h -68h` not used?
2. In `sub esp, 70h`, the number `70h` seems to be a random number in a different program, and it is often larger than we need. Why don't the compiler just allocate what we need?

Comment: Read [Why addresses of variable on stack are not consecutive?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/why-addresses-of-variable-on-stack-are-not-consecutive) and the answers there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case because *int* is 4 bytes and you want 20 element

```
int a[20] // --> 20 * 4 = 0x50
```

so it is very normal for *i* and *i_2*

The other thing is that your compiler didn't push *printf* arguments into stack. It pre-allocated the stack location in

```
var_70 = dword ptr -70h
var_6C = dword ptr -6Ch
var_68 = dword ptr -68h
```

and called the function like this

```
mov    edx, [esp+eax*4+70h+i_2]
mov    eax, offset aADD ; "a[%d]=%d\n"
mov    [esp+70h+var_68], edx
mov    edx, [esp+70h+i]
mov    [esp+70h+var_6C], edx
mov    [esp+70h+var_70], eax
call   _printf
```

But there is 2 reason for such a thing (not your case)...

1. The Compiler align the buffer for performance reasons and ease of cache.
   in addition unaligned buffers cause failure in some cases like Windows API calls and make debugging hard, so the compilers align every buffer to avoid this kind of failure.
2. Some safe compilation allocate random number after buffers to prevent successful exploitation of buffer overruns. for example:

   and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h

---

yeap! as @DCoder commented, you asked it [Here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/why-addresses-of-variable-on-stack-are-not-consecutive) before.

Comment: In that question, the answers says the temporary variables, like var_70 ,generated due to copy params are not local variables. But I think that's not correct.